# Oreo problem in creating a directory onto the external storage

Tags: java, android, directory, android-external-storage

I try to create folder in android external storage. I try many example but it all isn't worked. I set run-time permissions for reading and writing to external storage. It is work on Android API 6, 7. but not work on Android Oreo.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyDir");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        try {
            boolean is_seccess = f.mkdirs();
            if (is_seccess) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "not create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I Checked if external storage is available for read and write, it return true.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I give below permissions, I also give run-time permission and allow it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Just Android Oreo isn't work other device is working perfect. What is problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app requests READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the user grants it. If the app targets API level 25 or lower, the system also grants WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at the same time, because it belongs to the same STORAGE permission group and is also registered in the manifest. If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Ask run time permission like below:

```
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionReadStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int permissionWriteStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (permissionReadStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (permissionWriteStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this,
                listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```